# moment of inertia of a ring about an axis at 45° to the normal

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, moment-of-inertia

I wanted to calculate the moment of inertia of a ring about an axis at 45° to its normal outside the plane of the ring .

How do i calculate without using integration? I was thinking about using perpendicular axis theorom , but I need 2 axis in the plane of ring which I was unable to find . Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I=\sum\lambda_x^2I_x+\sum_{cyc}2\lambda_x\lambda_yI_{xy}$$

Where $\lambda_x \vec i+\lambda_y\vec j+\lambda_z\vec k$ is the unit vector along which moment of inertia is required.

$I_{xy}$ is $\sum xy dm$ which is zero due to symmetry when you take origin at centre of ring as for every pair $(x,y)$ you can find $(-x,-y)$. Also, other terms in second summation contain $z$ term which is zero as body is in $xy$ plane. Hence, the second summation is zero.

Now we should talk about first summation. $I_z=mR^2$ and $I_x=I_y=\frac 1 2 I_z$.

The unit vector you want is $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\vec i+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \vec k$.

You can apply the above formula

You can derived the above general result easily from vectors and taking cross products. Assume a tiny particle at $\vec r(x,y,z)$ and its distance from required axis is $d=|\vec r \times  \vec\lambda|$. Now find $md^2$.

Comment: I am sorry , can u elaborate a bit more , i am not able to understand

Comment: @user142634 Done.

Comment: knw why the question is put on hold ???

Comment: Because we do not entertain no effort homework questions. Read our homework policy